# Program design concerning ADTs

Tags: haskell

I have a type

```
data Phase = PhaseOne
           | PhaseTwo
           | PhaseThree deriving Enum
```

and five operations to do on each Phase

- `read`
- `write`
- `validate`
- `evalStatus`
- `update`

I began trying to create a type class. The problem is, they are all the same type.
I'd like to be able to do something like

```
instance MyClass PhaseThree where
  read a = ...
```

Also, I need to overload the return type.

I know type classes aren't what I want. But I'm not sure how to do what I want. I thought
of a GADT but that's not quite right as I need to be able to have each instance in a separate file.

I'd like some advice on which mechanisms I need to investigate? Have I given enough information?

Comment: If you define separate functions for `readPhaseOne`, `readPhaseTwo`, `writePhaseOne`, `writePhaseTwo`, etc., what would their types be?

Comment: it would help if you had slightly more information.  What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?  Why won't plain pattern matching work?  Why does Phase need to be one type instead of three?

Comment: Phillip : What I am trying to do is make an eDSL based on the above operations. Plain pattern-matching won't work because I am trying to overload the return type. Phase needs to be an enumerated type (need the succ method), therefor can only be one type instead of three (AFAIK).

Comment: A `read` for each of these `Phase`s wouldn't be terribly useful anyway, would it? It could only be `read = const PhaseOne`, `read = const PhaseTwo` and `read = const PhaseThree`.

Comment: well, I've tried to simplify the problem description without leaving out relevant information. But it seems I keep discovering important details I am leaving out. In this case what `read` looks like would be dependent on which Phase.

Comment: Heatsink : all read operations have the same type. Simplifying here - read :: JobID -> FooMonadStack ()

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: what if you had three types and created a class with  an associated type `Succ`, or multi-param type class where the `succ` type was a fundep?

Comment: @jberryman could you flesh that out a bit? I'm not clear on the syntax exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend inverting things a bit.

```
data Phase = Phase {
    read :: String -> Foo,
    write :: Foo -> IO (),
    validate :: Foo -> Bool,
    evalStatus :: IO (),
    update :: Foo -> Foo
}

phaseOne, phaseTwo, phaseThree :: Phase
```

(or some similar rejiggering of classes into explicit records).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment above, if you wanted to use three different types with a class supporting your operations, you can sort of build in an `Enum`-like functionality with a `succ` class method.

You also have to provide a `Done` type as a placeholder for `succ PhaseThree`

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses , FunctionalDependencies #-}
data PhaseOne = PhaseOne
data PhaseTwo = PhaseTwo
data PhaseThree = PhaseThree

data Done = Done

class YourClass p0 p1 | p0 -> p1 where
    succ :: p0 -> p1
    -- read :: ...
    -- write :: ...etc

instance YourClass PhaseOne PhaseTwo where
    succ PhaseOne = PhaseTwo
    -- read = ...

instance YourClass PhaseTwo PhaseThree where
    succ PhaseTwo = PhaseThree

instance YourClass PhaseThree Done where
    succ PhaseThree = Done
```

You might separate the `Succ` functionality from your `read`, `write`, etc. methods and create two classes as well. Return values can be polymorphic.

`succ` on your original posted formulation is horrible since `succ PhaseThree` just throws an error. If you can get the type system working for your application, that's the ideal.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to run with this. I think it's exactly what I needed.